# Implementing dictionary of delegates taking argument of key type

Tags: c#

I would like to have a dictionary of delegates where the key is the type of argument the delegate takes.

However, I don't find any other option than using `object` for the value type:

```csharp
Dictionary<Type, object> delegates;
```

I can add delegates like this:

```
public void AddListener<T>(MyDelegateType<T> listener)
{
    delegates[typeof(T)] = listener;
}
```

This is forcing my invoke code to look like this:

```csharp
public void Emit(object argument)
{
    var target = delegates[argument.GetType()];
    target.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke").Invoke(target, new object[] { argument });
}
```

If I knew type of argument at compile time, I could get slightly better:

```charp
public void Emit<T>(T argument)
{
    var target = (MyDelegateType<T>) delegates[typeof(T)];
    target.Invoke(argument);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this with/without having the argument type available at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

If you have every delegate as `MyDelegateType<T>` you can add base class like `MyDelegateType` and even better interface `IMyDelegateType`. So yours dictionary will be `Dictionary<Type, IMyDelegateType> delegates;`.
If you prefer to use SOLID, you should implement interface in the target type, or use extended methods, if this types are not yours. You could also use class having target object as element.

Comment: AFAIK delegates cannot extend classes / interfaces in C#.

Comment: I assume that it is not `MyDelegateType` as class inherited from delegate, I assume `MyDelegateType<T>` just contains method `Invoke(T)`